# Windows Driver Samples: how to use the drivers?

Tags: windows, windows-driver

Windows Driver Samples folder contains a lot of examples.
Supposed I have build one of them (e.g. VirtualSerial2), I get a .dll and .inf.
Then I install the certificate and the driver using pnputil.exe.

Now I would like to use my driver (e.g. to create an instance of a virtual com).
How can I do this?

Comment: Looking at the [code](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/main/serial/VirtualSerial2/device.c#L83) and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/serports/installing-plug-and-play-serial-ports-and-com-ports), it looks like the system automatically assigns the device a port number. So you would just access it like any other COM port, for example `CreateFile("COM7")`.

Comment: Hi Luke, thank you for your answer. Yes I found that if I install the driver right clicking on the inf and selecting "install" it does not work but if I install it using devcon.exe I get the virtual COM. The command I used is: devcon install VirtualSerial2um.inf UMDF\VirtualSerial2um. However it is not possible to connect a serial terminal to this port.